# Puppeteer how to target a dynamic range of children elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Let's say I have such a simplified website I want to scrape:

```
<section class="entry-content">
    <p></p>
    <figure></figure>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <h3></h3>
    <p></p>
</section>
```

**EDIT** There are other tags, which I don't want to scrape, between the first p-Tag and the h2-tag.

I can scrape all the h2s and h3s by this lines of code:

```
const pageContent = await page.$$eval( headerSelector, elements => elements.map( element => {
    const masterHeader = ''
    const { textContent: header } = element
    const content = []
    const subHeader = []

    while ( ( element = element.nextElementSibling ) && element.tagName !== 'H2' ) {
        switch (element.tagName) {
            case 'P':
                content.push( element.textContent )
                break;
            case 'H3':
                subHeader.push( element.textContent )
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return { masterHeader, header, content, subHeader}
}))


let subContent = await page.$$eval( subHeaderSelector, elements => elements.map( element => {
    const masterHeader = ''
    const {textContent: header } = element
    const content = []
    const subHeader = []

    while ( ( element = element.nextElementSibling ) && element.tagName !== 'H3' && element.tagName !== 'H2' ) {
        switch (element.tagName) {
            case 'P':
                content.push( element.textContent )
                break
            case 'H2':
                masterHeader.push( element.textContent )
                break
            case 'H4':
                subHeader.push( element.textContent )
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    return { masterHeader, header, content, subHeader}
}))
```

Once I have extracted the data, and after I did some data manipulation, I concat the content in one variable: "content".

```
let content = pageContent.concat(subContent)
```

---

Now I figured out, that one part is missing. The first parts of the webpage. There are three paragraphs, which I do not scrape with the logic about ( btw the logic refers to the answers here: [Save extracted data in objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913793/save-data-in-corresponding-related-documents-rather-in-separated-arrays-puppe/73914054?noredirect=1#comment130510733_73914054))

However, I came up with the idea, to target the section and then the children of it. This does basically work, but i don't know how to set an end. Like in this case: I only want the first paragraphs because they don't have any h2 or h3-tag. From that part, where the page delivers a h2-tag, either logic from above will do its job.

```
const headlessSelector = 'section.entry-content'
const headlessContent = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    const masterHeader = ''
    const header = `About ${keyword}`
    const content = []
    const subHeader = []

    for (element of document.querySelector(selector).children) {
        switch (element.tagName) {
            case 'P':
                content.push( element.textContent )
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    return { masterHeader, header, content, subHeader}
}, headlessSelector)

console.log(headlessContent)
```

Maybe I am kinda over thinking this, but can anyone help please.

Comment: From what I gather it seems like you want to scrape the contents of the first three `<p>` elements, and then only the contents of any `<h2>` or `<h3>` elements after that, but no more contents of any of the following `<p>` elements. Did I get that right?

Comment: The current script gets all the H2 tags and the corresponding p-tags and h3 tags. And each h3-tag with its corresponding p-tags. Now i try to get only the first three p-tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape all the `p` tags up to the first `<h2>` the solution in your last snippet is pretty close. To stop at the first `<h2>`, simply make the following change:

```
const headlessSelector = 'section.entry-content'
const headlessContent = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
    const masterHeader = ''
    const header = `About ${keyword}`
    const content = []
    const subHeader = []

    for (const element of document.querySelector(selector).children) {
        // Replace the switch statement with this code
        if (element.tagName === 'P') {
            content.push(element.textContent)
        } else if (element.tagName === 'H2') {
            break
        }
    }
    return { masterHeader, header, content, subHeader}
}, headlessSelector)

console.log(headlessContent)
```

Using an if-else statement, rather than a switch statement allows you to use `break` to break out of the loop (instead of just ending the switch case), and stop concatenating the contents of any more elements, once you encounter a tag other than `<p>`.

It's possible to keep the switch statement and use labels and `goto`s to jump out of the loop, but that style of code has a tendency to be less readable and harder to reason about.

Comment: So far I can tell, it does work, because it stops when any other tag, besides the p-tag, shows up. So I figured out, that there are some other tags in between. I upated the question - sry for that.

Comment: All good, I've updated the code - Instead of breaking at the first non-`<p>` element, you can break once you actually encounter the `<h2>`

Comment: Thanks that works fine! So can I combine an OR with that else if statement: `if ( .. ) { .. } else if ( element.tagName === 'H2' || element.tagName === 'H3' ) { break }`

Comment: If you want it to stop on either an h2 or an h3, then yes that will work